# Deleting a dynamic array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a question concerning deleting a dynamic array of pointers in C++. Let's imagine that we have a following situation:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
Node **array1 = new Node*[n];
/* ... */
```

where Node is a certain structure defined beforehand. Suppose that after allocation with the new operator, we change the content of the array1 (but we do not delete anything!). What is the proper way to delete the array1 and all its content if there is a possibility of repeated pointers in the array (without sorting them or inserting into the set, in linear time)?

Comment: Are the pointers in the array themselves allocated on the heap?
If they are, you could add a reference count to Node or perhaps have another array that only contains unique pointers to allocated Nodes.

Comment: why is this tagged c++? if you're using c++ just use vectors for this.

Comment: Do you mean change the value of `array1` itself, or the pointers within it? You are not showing how the content of `array1` is being created in the code.

Comment: Don't use that horribleness in C++.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm going to assign certain values to the elements of the `array1`, so de facto I will change the pointers. Sorry for the obscurity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this allocation:

```
Node **array1 = new Node*[n];
```

The contents of array1 are *undefined*.  Each element is a `Node*`, and because the memory is uninitialized, the value could be anything.

Allocating an array of pointers does *not* construct objects of the pointed-to class.

So whatever pointers you put into the array, the objects they point to need to be constructed and destructed elsewhere.

So to answer your question, the proper way to delete array1 is

```
delete[] array1;
```

However, note that *this will not* result in destructors being called for each `Node*` - you should deal with whatever you put into the array *before* you delete the array.

EDIT:
I was confused by the original question, which mentioned "change the value" in the array, *as if there was* a valid value in the array as allocated in your example.

BUT... now that I understand you want to keep track of the pointers for deletion later, perhaps you can just create another array for that purpose where each pointer exists only once.  So you have the array you currently have above, which contains pointers to nodes that might be repeated, for whatever purpose you're using it.  Then you have another array *for the express purpose* of managing the deletion, where each pointer occurs only once.  It should be easy enough to set something like `nodeCleanupArray[i] = pNewNode` right after `pNewNode = new Node()`, then you can blast through that array in linear time and `delete` each element.  (Which means you wouldn't bother inspecting the elements in array1, you'd rely on nodeCleanupArray for the cleanup)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and thorough respond. However, how can I manage the repeating pointers in the `array1`? I can't use preimplemented dynamic data structures like `std::vector` or any other STL containers for this, because I'm not allowed to do so in my project.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted to do. Once again, sorry for the lack of clarity in my explanation of the problem but I didn't occur to have fun with the pointers to the pointers in C++ previously. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY solutions to this sort of problem, but the most obvious choice would be to change it to use

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> >
```

Now you will have a reference counted pointer without writing any code, and an "array" that doesn't need to know it's predefined size.

You can of course implement a reference counted object within `Node`, or your own container object to do the same thing, but that seems like extra hassle for little or no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try mark and sweep :) You are trying to implement a managed environment.

Here is an example:

```
struct Node
{
... 
    bool marked;

    Node() : marked(false)
    {}
};
```

Now delete:

```
void do_delete(Node **data, size_t n)
{
    size_t uniq = 0;
    Node **temp = new Node*[n];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] && !data[i]->marked)
        {
            data[i]->marked = true;
            temp[uniq++] = data[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < uniq; ++i)
    {
        delete temp[i];
    } 

    delete[] temp;
    delete[] data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is have a reference counters and have a Node::deref method that would delete the node itself when reference count is 0.  When iterating through the list of nodes, calling node->deref will not actually delete the object until the last Node reference in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to delete the array1 and all its content

You show a single allocation; `new Node*[n]`. This allocation confers on the program the responsibility to call `delete [] whatever_the_return_value_was`. This is only about deleting that one allocation and not about deleting 'all its content'. If your program performs other allocations then the program needs to arrange for those responsibilities to be handled as well.

> if there is a possibility of repeated pointers in the array

Well it would be undefined behavior to `delete` a pointer value that is not associated with any current allocation, so you have to avoid deleting the same pointer value more than once. This is not an issue of there being a single correct way, but an issue of programming practices, design, etc.

Typically C++ uses RAII to handle this stuff automatically instead of trying to do what you want by hand, because doing it by hand is really hard to get right. One way to use RAII here would be to have a second object that 'owns' the Nodes. Your `array1` would then simply use raw pointers as 'non-owning' pointers. Deleting all the Nodes then would be done by letting the Node owning object go out of scope or otherwise be destroyed.

```
{
  // object that handles the ownership of Node objects.
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> node_owner;

  // your array1 object that may hold repeated pointer values.
  std::vector<Node*> array1;

  node_owner.emplace_back(new Node); // create new nodes

  array1.push_back(node_owner.back().get()); // put nodes in the array
  array1.push_back(node_owner.back().get()); // with possible duplicates

  // array1 gets destroyed, but it's contents do not, so the repeated pointers don't matter
  // node_owner gets destroyed and destroys all its Nodes. There are no duplicates to cause problems.
}
```

And the destruction does occur in linear time.